# Detecting a touch with Swift/SKScene

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I'm trying to figure out how to detect a touch anywhere on the screen with a subclass of SKScene so that I can transition. How do I do so?

Thanks

Comment: Use touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)

Answer (score 0):

```
       override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

      let location = touch.location(in: self)


      print(location)

     //if your touch location = a button or anything it transitions to a new scene 
       if location = //Startbutton {
       let transition = SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 0.75)
     let gameScene = GameScene(size: size)
     gameScene.scaleMode = scaleMode
     view?.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
```

Prints the users touch location... hope that helps a bit m8

Comment: you need to be careful with your answer,  it doesn't take into affect any node on the scene that also has `isUserInteractionEnabled` set to true. Those nodes touch events would get called instead of this one.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon How do you handle that? Use nodesAt:(Point:) and then iterate over the returned array for an SKScene?

Comment: @SteveIves Honestly, I would either use a tap gesture or an overlay node, but if no other node can be touched,  I would use this approach because it is simple